# Minimise a function taking a vector as an input directly

Tags: functions, vector

```
f1[x_] := x*2 // Abs;
f2[x_] := (x // Transpose).x;
Minimize[f1[x], {x}] (* fine, returns 0 *)
Minimize[f2[x], {x}] (* not fine, returns "Minimize[Transpose[x].x, x]" *)
```

A workaround for this would be to do:

```
Minimize[f2[{{a}, {b}}], {a, b}]
{0, {a -> 0, b -> 0}}
```

However, that isn't very nice when X is a long vector.

Is there a way to minimise a function taking a vector directly without resorting to workarounds?

If I have to use a workaround, is there a way to automate what I did in that example maybe using "macros"?

Comment: When I run the code Minimize[f1[x], {x}] returns 0

Comment: @Jagra there was a mistake I switched f1 with f2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on edlo's answer, I have come up with the following shortcut:

```
CreateVarsList[n_] := Table[Unique[], {n}]; (* get n list of vars *)
CreateVarsList[x_, n_] := 
 Array[ToExpression[x <> ToString[#]] &, n]; (* get n list of vars named xi *)
```

Now I can do:

```
mini = Minimize[J[{#} // Transpose], #] & @ CreateVarsList[28]
```

Where J(theta) takes a vector of length 28. Previously I would have to type a list of 28 variables twice.

Comment: you could define f2 as `{x}.{x}` which is the same as `x^2`. Transposing is not possible here.

Comment: The `Array`/`ToExpression`/`ToString` stuff is arguably unnecessary. Creation of sequentially numbered symbols is the job of `Unique`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I have added another definition based on what you suggested. Thanks !

Comment: @eldo I don't get what you mean. I'm multiplying a vector (column) by each row in a matrix to produce another vector (column) so that would be X*Transpose(theta) = y where  X(m*n) , theta(n*1) and y(m*1).

Answer (score 1):

Would that work?

```
Minimize[f2@#, #] & /@ {a, b, c}
```

Comment: thanks, that's a clever way of making it shorter !

Comment: It should be "@" not "/@" though

Comment: @Spacemonkey - Reproducing your question, I found that "f1" doesn't work whereas f2 works - it's just the opposite.

Comment: I made a mistake and switched f1 with f2 in my question, fixed now.